# My current if statement with the logical II OR is having compile error

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators

I am learning Java and following code is not working, can you please check and see what I did wrong? Thanks.

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        /*
         Ticket price: 10 normally

        Discounted price , 5 for:
        - Age 15 and under
        - Over the age 60
        - Students
        */
        int ticketPrice = 10;
        int age = 16;
        boolean isStudent = false;
        
        if( (age =< 15) || (age>60) ){
            ticketPrice = 5;
        }else if (isStudent){
            ticketPrice = 5;
        }
        System.out.println("The price is: "+ ticketPrice);
     }
}
```

Comment: try so: ```age <= 15```

Comment: Looks ok to me.  Can you be more specific about what you see that is "not working?"

Comment: Note for the future: always be specific about the problem. In this case, it's a compile-time error... but you haven't told us that, or what the error is. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and bear it in mind for future questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's **<=** (Less than or Equal to), not `=<`.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        /*
        Ticket price: 10 normally

        Discounted price , 5 for:
        - Age 15 and under
        - Over the age 60
        - Students          */
    
        int ticketPrice = 10;
        int age = 16;
        boolean isStudent = false;

        if ( (age <= 15) || (age>60) || (isStudent) )
            ticketPrice = 5;
        System.out.println("The price is: "+ ticketPrice);
    }
}
```